# How to run docker load in remote server

Tags: docker, batch-file, sudo, plink

I am trying to run `docker load` in a remote server. here is my code

```
plink.exe -ssh myuser@174.123.32.232 -pw mypass -no-antispoof "echo mypass   | sudo -S  docker load < my-server-code.tar 2> /dev/null"
```

however the image doesnt get loaded

however when I run

```
echo mypass   | sudo -S  docker load < my-server-code.tar
```

from the remote server it works
I do observer there are alot of loadings going on like the following

[image]

is that affecting the remote call?

Comment: wouldn't be easier to just assign the docker group to that user? You won't have to use sudo and provide the password. BTW, you can also use `docker load -i my-server-code.tar`. BTW, what error are you getting when performing the first command?

Comment: no error pops out

Comment: I'm sure you'll get something if you remove the 2> /dev/null

Comment: "assign the docker group to that user" how do you do that?

Comment: sudo usermod -G docker $(whoami)

Comment: I added the 2> /dev/null to provide the password to sudo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223934/discussion-between-stefano-and-adhil).

Comment: if you can post an answer I can choose it as the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To assign the docker group to your user (please note that there might be some security concerns in doing this):

```sh
usermod -G docker $(whoami)
```

To load the images, you can use:

```sh
docker load -i filename.tar
```

Another possible approach might be to define the command in the sudoers file. Check the `/etc/sudoers` and add something like this:

```
Cmnd_Alias DOCKER_LOAD_CMD = docker load -i file.tar
user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: DOCKER_LOAD_CMD
```

If you plan to follow this, you should check very carefully with a second terminal open if there are errors of any kind (you might break the sudo functionality and that's not fun)

Comment: "Some security concerns" => "if you can run any `docker` command at all, it's almost trivial to root the host"